# Are question marks (?) allowed in URL passwords (netloc)?

Tags: python, url, rfc

I've run into a bug in my code which boils down to unexpected behaviour in python's urllib.parse.urlparse.  It happens when a a password in an URL contains `?`.  I'm very shy to call this a bug because I'm not 100% certain the URLs are syntactically correct.  For example:

```
https://user:pass?word@domain.name/path
```

I'd expect this to parse as:

```
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='user:pass?word@domain.name', path='/path', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

But it actually parses as:

```
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='user:pass', path='', params='', query='word@domain.name/path', fragment='')
```

---

These URL's are being automatically formatted elsewhere and the use of `?` in the password needs to be supported.  Interestingly enough, the URLS are actually sqlalchemy connection strings and sqlalchemy / psycopg2 are both interpreting them as expected.

---

#### Question

Are question marks `?` allowed in an URL Password (netloc)? - Ideally answers would refer to the appropriate RFC wording.

Or is python's behaviour here correct?

Comment: User and password are not part of the HTTP specification. It might be accepted by some browsers but it is not standard. Look at [RFC 2616](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-3.2.2).

Comment: @Matthias this question is not about HTTP.  I just happened to use a HTTP scheme URL as an example.  RFC 2616 doesn't define URL syntax, the section above the one you linked explicitly states that's defined in [RFC 2396](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2396) which I think *does* define username and password [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2396#section-3.2.2)

Comment: @OmerTuchfeld That should be posted as an answer rather than as a comment. Comments are temporary and cannot be accepted as an answer. There is no mechanism for converting comments to answers, so I cannot do it for you. You will need to copy your comment into the answer box and then delete your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section 3.2 in RFC 2396 specifies that `?` is reserved in the authority component (which means you're not allowed to use it within that component without encoding, see 2.2). The authority component, IIUC, is the component encompassing the user-name/password of an HTTP scheme URI (see 3.2.2).